# PHP - how to insert lines in MySQL from a text file when the rows are inconsistent

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

I have a proxy app that is generating log files in a text file that is inconsistent from one row to the next. Depending on what the row is reporting, some pieces of data will be present or missing. Here's an example:

```
2012-08-05 10:48:59 Login.Failure   [ip address]    12312191391921
2012-08-05 10:49:05 Login.Success   [ip address]    19919292912912  IQi8CaVGiXoPXGy
2012-08-05 12:50:57 Logout      19919292912912  IQi8CaVGiXoPXGy Expired
```

There are seven possible values, but as you can see, they are not all present all the time.

I want to enter these values in a database so I can create statistics. So far I'm guessing I need to look into the array at position 2 (0,1,2) and if it matches a certain string, only expect *these* items to be there, and if it matches another string, only expect *these* items, etc.

So far my thinking has gotten to the point of interrupting the array and adding a new condition depending on the value it has found. That doesn't work, I know, but this is as far as I have gotten in my thinking:

```
$output = explode("\n", $output);
foreach($output as $var) {
$tmp = explode(" ", $var);
$dateentered = $tmp[0];
$timeentered = $tmp[1];
$event = $tmp[3];

if  $tmp[3]="Login.Failure" then

$IP = $tmp[4];
$username = $tmp[5];

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die('unable to connect');

mysql_select_db('dbname') or die('unable to select database');

$sql = "INSERT INTO table SET dateentered='$dateentered', timeentered='$timeentered', event='$event', IP ='$IP ', username='$username'";

$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die('Error in query: $query. ' .mysql_error());


else if $tmp[3]="Login.Success" then

$IP = $tmp[4];
$username = $tmp[5];
$session = $tmp[6];
```

...and so on...

I want to be able to pull out all the successes and sum them, then do the same with failures, and so on.

How would you approach this? If someone even just has an idea of a sensible workflow, I can build from there. I am obviously just a beginner, though I do have several pages under my belt.

Thanks for any and all replies.

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't your database structure like this:

```
2012-08-05 10:48:59 Login.Failure   [ip address]    12312191391921  NULL            NULL
2012-08-05 10:49:05 Login.Success   [ip address]    19919292912912  IQi8CaVGiXoPXGy NULL
2012-08-05 12:50:57 Logout          NULL            19919292912912  IQi8CaVGiXoPXGy Expired
```

Or like this:

```
2012-08-05 10:48:59 Login.Failure   [ip address]    12312191391921  ""              ""
2012-08-05 10:49:05 Login.Success   [ip address]    19919292912912  IQi8CaVGiXoPXGy ""
2012-08-05 12:50:57 Logout          ""              19919292912912  IQi8CaVGiXoPXGy Expired
```

Maintaining the correct data in the correct columns, or rather maintaining associative data in the same column should be prioritized.

To address you code, I believe this solution will work:

```
$output;                            // data gotten from file
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") 
  or die('unable to connect');      // connect to DB
mysql_select_db('dbname')           // select DB
  or die('unable to select database');
$output = explode("\n", $output);   // tokenize input by lines
for($i=0; $i<count($output); $i++) {// for each line
  $tmp = explode(" ", $output[i]);  // tokenize lines by spaces
  $dateentered = $tmp[0];           // set required data
  $timeentered = $tmp[1];           // set required data
  $event    = $tmp[3];              //i think this should be [2]
  $IP       = "";                   // set default value of possible data
  $username = "";                   // set default value of possible data
  $session  = "";                   // set default value of possible data
  $expired  = "";                   // set default value of possible data

       if ($event=="Login.Failure") { 
    $IP       = $tmp[4];            //i think this should be [3]
    $username = $tmp[5];            //i think this should be [4]
  } 
  else if ($event=="Login.Success") {
    $IP       = $tmp[4];            //i think this should be [3]
    $username = $tmp[5];            //i think this should be [4]
    $session  = $tmp[6];            //i think this should be [5]
  }
  else if ($event=="Logout") {
    $username = $tmp[5];            //i think this should be [4]
    $session  = $tmp[6];            //i think this should be [5]
    $expired  = $tmp[7];            //i think this should be [6]
  }
/*
 * Update DB:
 */
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table SET "
        ."dateentered='$dateentered', "
        ."timeentered='$timeentered', "
        ."event='$event', "
        ."IP ='$IP', " 
        ."username='$username', "
        ."session='$session', "
        ."expired='$expired'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql,$connection) 
    or die('Error in query: $query. ' .mysql_error() 
          .'\n\nWhile Processing line $i');
}                                   // closing brace of for loop
mysql_close($connection);           // close connection to DB
```

Questions about your code:

- where is/what is `$tmp[2]`; I think your indexing might be off by 1

Also be sure to review my code to make sure it behaves as you want it to be for blinding plugging it into you database. I think I interpreted you problem correctly and presented a working solution but only you can be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You will really need to validate each row that you insert into your database. I would probably use a simple function to do that with it returning either a proper delimited string or an array that you can append to the insert statement.

From the looks of your example text, the text is tab delimited, so that's a start. In the function you can explode on that at least to get the individual items. Going with that, they seem to be rather different one after another, which is also good, it means your logic to understand which ones are missing should be easy.

This really simple code should get you started...

```
function findMyFields($inputString)
{
    $tArray=explode('\t', $string);
    if(str_len($tArray[0])==19) 
    // the dateTime looks to be 19 characters and will stay fixed length
    {
        $returnString=$tArray[0].',';
    }
    else
    {
        $returnString=null.',';
    }
    // and so on for each field.

    return $returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an associative array where the key is the log entry type (`Login.Success`,`Login.Failure`, etc.), and the value is an array of entries.

Then loop through the array by the first key. Since you know what fields to expect for each log type; its a simply case of creating a template SQL query (with proper escaping of course).